# How does Whitebox labs get isolated sensor boards when they are using a single power supply?

Tags: pcb, sensor, opto-isolator, isolation

Whitebox labs makes "Electrically Isolated EZO™ Carrier Boards" which are isolated boards for Atlas Scientific sensors such as pH.

I don't understand how can you get an isolated board if they are only using one power supply the same one as the Raspberry Pi or Arduino.

Is an opto coupler really necessary here?

Does it improve the sensor accuracy in any way? Are the grounds really different?

[Here is the  datasheet for one such board.](https://files.atlas-scientific.com/electrically-isolated-ezo-carrier-board.pdf)

Comment: I linked the datasheet to the old version of the board. Here is the new one https://www.atlas-scientific.com/files/Gen2-usb-iso-specs.pdf. But I have learned from the answers already how it works. The new one uses a single chip for data and power isolation ADM3260.

Comment: please do not use comments to add information to your question ... edit the question instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last page of the datasheet has a diagram.

[image]

It shows that the board uses an [RFM-0505](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/468/RFM-1710978.pdf) isolated DC-DC converter to power the isolated side of the [SI8600 bidirectional I2C isolator.](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/Si860x.pdf)

One side of the board operates on the power from the Raspberry Pi or Arduino while the other side of the board operates on power from the RFM-0505.

The grounds are really separate.  The isolation doesn't really do much for accuracy - the data is digital so it doesn't matter really much at all whether you read it straight or through the isolator.

Where the isolation matters is that with the isolated ground separate from the microcontroller ground it is much more difficult for disturbances from the controller and its power supplu to get in the stuff you are trying to test.

Comment: Thank you for a very fast response! You answered my question.

Comment: I just found out that the newer version of this board uses this chip ADM3260 which is I think for both power and data isolation.

Comment: It also makes it difficult for disturbances on the measuring side (e.g. short circuit) to break the microcontroller

Answer (score 2):

They use 2 ics that isolate, the RFM-0505 and the Si8600. One does power and the other does data. This allows the EZO circuit to be isolated from the potentially noisy data and ground sections that are connected to the data section.

And yes it is necessary, I usually use schemes like this in analog electronics that measure nano-volts, it improves signal to noise ratio by reducing the noise (you see less 'spikes' in the signal)

[image]
Source: https://files.atlas-scientific.com/electrically-isolated-ezo-carrier-board.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In the diagram at the bottom of the [document you linked](https://files.atlas-scientific.com/electrically-isolated-ezo-carrier-board.pdf) it shows that they are using two power supplies, VCC/GND and ISO-VCC/ISO-GND.

The carrier board only uses one supply but it goes through another module that provides the isolation. Read the section titled 'Data isolation'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "opto coupler". It's a *capacitive* isolation scheme for data and *transformer* isolation for power.

Anyway, the smarts are in the [Skyworks chip](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/SL/documents/public/data-sheets/Si860x.pdf) and the power isolation is provided by a [5V:5V DC-DC isolated output module](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/468/RFM-1710978.pdf) (transformer isolation in the latter case).

Galvanic isolation can provide major advantages in certain case, for example, a thermocouple may have a grounded junction so any difference in ground potentials would  represent a large common-mode voltage. pH sensors are another case where there is conductivity to ground in many cases.

And yes, the grounds are different, though there may be some AC voltage introduced as a result of the DC-DC converter.

Comment: Thank you for a very fast response! Oh and thanks for the correction about the capacitive isolation.

Comment: A sub-question to the original, does such isolation protect the sensor from large voltage if Raspberry pi power supply fails for example?

Comment: It might. On the other hand failures in the board are possible, but it's unlikely to present many volts. It does provide a second barrier between the mains and the sensor. Usually we're pretty confident in the mains power supplies because decent ones meet a lot of safety agency design rules and testing.